# VBA - Get data of array inside another array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I have created an array that contains another array into it, but now I am struggling to get the data from it. Please see the image attached.

Imagine I would like to access the string in channelsData(1)(1,1)(0,0) so the first red crossed string. How can I call it in an If condition condition for example?

[image: Array Inside Array]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you declare the array? It's probably just `channelsData(1,1)(0,0)`

Comment: @Rory I have declared the array like this channelsData(1 To numFiles, 0 To 2) and then put another array from another function in channelsData(i, 1)

Comment: And did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Please post the code that both declares and populates the array.

Comment: @Rory it works. thanks. I was also looking to count the index in (1,1)(0). I have tried the UBound(channelsData(1,1)(0)) but does not work.

Comment: Try: `UBound(channelsData(1,1))`

Comment: @Rory thanks, but that gives the dimension of the first column. I managed to get it by UBound(channelsData(i, 1), 2).

Answer (score 0):

To get the data is as @Rory suggested. channelsData(1,1)(0,0)

To get the dimension of the array at channelsData(1,1)(i) is UBound(channelsData(i, 1), 2)